# How to set language by domain name extension

Tags: grails

I would like to set language of my website depending of domain extension.

Example :

```
mywebsite.com  -->  english
mywebsite.fr   -->  french
```

Have you advices about how to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I'm using in my project:

```
class OverrideTagLib extends ValidationTagLib {

  Closure message = { attrs ->
    if( !attrs.locale ){
      def dm = grailsApplication.config.grails.domainMapping
      attrs.locale = new Locale( dm[ request.serverName ] ?: dm[ null ] )
    }
    out << messageImpl( attrs )
  }

}
```

and the `grailsApplication.config.grails.domainMapping` is defined in `Config.groovy` as:

```
grails.domainMapping = [
  'www.mywebsite.com':'en',
  'www.mywebsite.eu':'fr',
  'www.mywebsite.de':'de',
  'localhost':'ru',
  (null):'en'
]
```